# Convert seconds to Day, Hour, Minute and Second

Tags: math, f#

I'm trying to convert a certain value of seconds to the following format, using F#:

00d 00h 00m 00s

And I'm sure I'm doing the correct calc but it also gives me wrong minutes. My code is the following:

```
let sum = 266521
let day = sum / 86400
let leftover = sum % 86400

let hour = leftover / 3600
leftover = leftover % 3600

let minute = leftover / 60
leftover = leftover % 60
```

---

```
86400 -> Seconds in a day
3600 -> Seconds in an hour
60 -> Seconds in a minute.
```

I'm trying to do this greedy calc, but it gives me the values:
3d 2h 122m 7321s

But it can't be 122m, it should be in hour. I don't understand where is my error.
Can you help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Pay attention to compiler warnings. The problematic lines produce `This expression should have type 'unit', but has type 'bool'. Use 'ignore' to discard the result of the expression, or 'let' to bind the result to a name.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about just leveraging the built-in functionality?

```
> open System;;
> let secs = 266521;;

val secs : int = 266521

> let s = (TimeSpan.FromSeconds (float secs)).ToString "d\d\ hh\h\ mm\m\ ss\s";;

val s : string = "3d 02h 02m 01s"
```

Comment: True, but the exercise is worthwhile in pointing out subtleties with F# coding in a concrete example.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the values are immutable (cannot change) in F#. Your value "leftover" stays at the value 7321, its first value. This is done to help with threading and data sharing. Either create a new value when changing the value of "leftover" or otherwise make the value mutable:

```
let mutable leftover = sum % 86400
leftover <- leftover % 3600
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
leftover = leftover % 3600
```

is a boolean expression that compares `leftover` to `leftover % 3600` (which probably evaluates to false). What you need to do, is to assign a new value,

```
let leftover' = leftover % 3600
```

and then use `leftover'` subsequently.